# undefined this inside next.js arrow function method

Tags: reactjs, next.js, this

I am attempting to call a method from a onClick event inside a class component:

```
export default class WhiteListOptions extends Component {

    triggerPurchase = async (buyQty) => {
        await this.props.purchaseFunction(buyQty);
    }

    render () {
        return (
                        <button onClick={_ => this.triggerPurchase("5000")} className="buy-btn">Buy Now</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Yet, for some reason it is treating "this" as undefined inside the function scope when I call props:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: Arrow functions do not have `this` bindings. Try converting `triggerPurchase` to a regular function, i.e. `async triggerPurchase(buyQty) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `.bind(this)` is what you are looking for.

Putting `.bind(this)` after the function call you will force the function to use the context of the class.

```
export default class WhiteListOptions extends Component {

    triggerPurchase = async (buyQty) => {
        await this.props.purchaseFunction(buyQty);
    }

    render () {
        return (
                        <button onClick={_ => this.triggerPurchase.bind(this,"5000")} className="buy-btn">Buy Now</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't working... The onclick event doesn't even execute the function now